# package org.junit does not exist using Terminal

Tags: java, junit, cmd

I am trying to run a JUnit test file in the Terminal with the following command :

```
C:\work\apps\jdk1.8.0_131-x64\bin\java -jar C:\work\apps\jdk1.8.0_131-x64\bin\junit-4.13.2.jar 
C:\Users\silvacl1\Desktop\actimizemse-batch- 
java\src\main\java\com\natixis\tests\junit\JunitTests
```

but I receive the following error:
no main manifest attribute, in C:\work\apps\jdk1.8.0_131-x64\bin\junit-4.13.2.jar

If I attempt to compile this file first with the command :

```
C:/work/apps/jdk1.8.0_131-x64/bin/javac -cp     
C:/Users/silvacl1/.m2/repository/com/github/noraui/ojdbc8/12.2.0.1/ojdbc8- 
12.2.0.1.jar;C:/Users/silvacl1/.m2/repository/com/sun/mail/javax.mail/1.6.2/javax.mail- 
1.6.2.jar;C:/Users/silvacl1/.m2/repository/commons-lang/commons-lang/2.6/commons-lang- 
2.6.jar;C:/Users/silvacl1/.m2/repository/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpcore/4.4/httpcore- 
4.4.jar;C:/Users/silvacl1/.m2/repository/org/junit.jar;. -d out -sourcepath . 
src/main/java/com/natixis/tests/main/TestsMain.java src/main/java/com/natixis/ws/util/*.java 
src/main/java/com/natixis/tests/junit/*.java 
src/main/java/com/natixis/tests/junit/JunitTests.java             
src\main\java\com\natixis\tests\junit\JunitTests.java
```

I get the error :
package org.junit does not exist

I tried to edit the pom.xml file :

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>junit</groupId>
  <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
  <version>4.13</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

But both errors persist.
Can someone help ?
Thank you very much!

Comment: There is no need to ever invoke `java` or `javac` when working with Maven (`mvn test`should do)

Answer (score 0):

Your JUNIT is in `<scope>test</scope>` So is visible only by `mvn test ...` If you need use `java -jar ...` delete `<scope>test</scope>` in your Maven pom file.